# Orthogonality of eigenfunctions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

We considere the following problem:
$$
\begin{cases}
y''+\lambda y=0\\
y(0)-2y(2\pi)=0\\
y'(0)-y'(2\pi)=0
\end{cases}
$$
I found that the eigenfunctions of the problem are 
$$
y_n(x)= \cos(nx)+ \sin(nx), \ n \in \mathbb{Z}^\star.
$$
The first question is to prove that the eigenfunctions are orthogonal, then i found that $\displaystyle\int_0^{2 \pi} y_n(x) y_m(x) dx =0$.
The second question is: prove that $\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi} y_n^2(x) dx =1$

We have 
$$
\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi} y_n^2(x) dx= 2\pi + \displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(nx) \sin(nx) dx$$
My question is: How do we find that the result is 1? Please

edit:
When $\lambda >0$ we put $\lambda=\alpha^2$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^\star_+$ then the general solution of the equation is 
$$y
(x)= C_1 \cos(\alpha x)+ C_2 \sin(\alpha x)$$

Then we have $$y(0)-2 y(2\pi)=0 =>C_1(1-2\cos(2\pi \alpha))-2C_2 \sin(2\pi\alpha)=0$$ and $$y'(0)-y'(2\pi)=0 =>C_1 \sin(2\pi \alpha)+C_2(1-\cos(2\pi\alpha))=0$$ then this last system do not admits the trivial solution iff $\cos(2\pi\alpha)=1$ then $\alpha=k \in \mathbb{Z}^\star$. So the eigenvalues for the problem are $\lambda=k^2$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}^\star$ and the eigenfunctions are $$y_k(x)=C_1 \cos(kx)+C_2 \sin(kx)$$ Where is the error? Please

Comment: Your $y_n$ does not satisfy the second equation of the system, which would reduce to $1=2$.

Comment: In addition, you must multiply your eigenfunction with a constant, that in turn should be determined by the normalization condition $\int_0^{2\pi}y_n^2(x)\,dx=1$.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understant your suggestion. I edit my forst message, can you see it and help me please

Comment: mickep Sorry but i don't understant how we normalize? Please

Comment: I tink $C_1=0$ and $C_2$ anything you need to normalize the solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y_n^2=(\cos(nx)+\sin(nx))^2=\\
\cos(nx)^2+\sin(nx)^2+2\cos(nx)\sin(nx)=\\
1+2\cos(nx)\sin(nx).$

Since  $\sin(nx)\cos(nx)=(1/2)sin(2nx)$, the integral evaluates to $x-cos(2nx)(1/n)|_{0}^{2\pi}=2\pi -1(1/n)-0+1(1/n)=2\pi.$

Comment: Thank you but we must find $1$. How we can find 1? Whow we normalize? Please

Comment: jiji As @mickep suggested, your eigenfunctions can be multiplied by an arbitrary constant c. If we choose $c=1/(2\pi)$, then your functions are normalised.

Comment: @jiji Simply so: using $\bar y_n$ instead of $y_n$, with $\bar y_n=y_n/(2\pi)$

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I edit my first message. My solution is true? Please